# sequelize : Create new entry with existing foreign key

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I create 2 models :

```
userPreferenceCategories = sequelize.define("userPreferenceCategories", {
    id : {
        type          : Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement : true,
        primaryKey    : true,
        allowNull     : false
    },
    name : {
        type      : Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull : false
    }
}, {
    indexes: [
        {
            unique : true,
            fields : ["name"]
        }
    ],
    freezeTableName : true
});
```

and

```
userPreferenceCategoryTypes =  sequelize.define("userPreferenceCategoryTypes", {
    id : {
        type          : Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement : true,
        primaryKey    : true,
        allowNull     : false
    },
    name : {
        type      : Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull : false
    }
}, {
    indexes: [
        {
            unique : true,
            fields : ["name", "userPreferenceCategoryId"]
        }
    ],
    freezeTableName : true
});
```

With relation :

```
userPreferenceCategoryTypes.belongsTo(userPreferenceCategories, {
    onDelete   : "cascade",
    onUpdate   : "cascade",
    foreignKey : {
        field     : "userPreferenceCategoryId",
        allowNull : false,
    }
});
```

one time, I create an userPreferenceCategories entry :

```
userPreferenceCategories.upsert({name : "cat1"});
```

in second time, I would like create an userPreferenceCategoryTypes associate at "cat1" like this :

```
userPreferenceCategoryTypes.upsert({
    name : "type1",
    userPreferenceCategory : {
        name : "cat1"
    }
}, {
    include: [ {
        model : userPreferenceCategories
    } ]
});
```

but this don't work with message :

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeValidationError: notNull Violation: userPreferenceCategoryId cannot be null
```

In fact, sequelize does not seem to add userPreferenceCategoyId attribut on sql request. How can I insert new entry in userPreferenceCategoryTypes this foreignKey of cat ? I don't execute that on series.

EDIT 1 :

I found a solution but I'm not sure if there had better : /

```
userPreferenceCategory.find({where: {name: "cat1"}}).then(function (cat) {
    UserPreferenceCategoryType.create({
        name : "type1",
        userPreferenceCategoryId : cat.getDataValue("id")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's the only solution

> No, because when you do a create with include, it will create the
>   associated instance, not associate it.