# Insert into one-to-many relationship table using sequelize with existing foreign key

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, associations, one-to-many

I am having the following models:

```
Sports.init({
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {sequelize, tableName: 'sports'});
    
Leagues.init({
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {sequelize, tableName: 'leagues'});
```

The association between them is the following.

```
Sports.Leagues = Sports.hasMany(Leagues, {foreignKey: {name: "sports_id", allowNull: false}, sourceKey: "id"});
Leagues.Sports = Leagues.belongsTo(Sports, {foreignKey: {name: "sports_id", allowNull: false}, targetKey: "id"});
```

I already have a record in the Sports table: `{name: "Basketball", id: 1}`
I want to create a record in the Leagues table referencing this already existing sports record.
How can I do that with one function? I went through the documentation, but did not find anything appropriate there. I know I would be able to do it the following way, in case if the record, which I am referencing to, does not exist:

```
await Leagues.create({name: leagueName, espn_name: espnName, Sport: {name: "Basketball"}}, {include: Leagues.Sports});
```

However, I did not find anything about how to do it, if the foreign key already exists, besides manually doing something like this:

```
await Sports.findOne({where: {name: sportName}}).then((res) => {
        if(res) {
            return Leagues.create({name: leagueName, espn_name: espnName, sports_id: res.get("id")});
        }
    });
```

For me, it seems like too much code for a relatively simple operation. Is there any "smarter" or shorter way of doing that?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just indicating sports_id isn't short enough?

Comment: @Anatoly At the point, where I am creating league record, I only have sport name, I do not have its id. To indicate sports_id, I need to query first it from the database by sport name. This is why it does not look "short" enough for me. I hope I could do it with one command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I found similar question on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39788390/sequelize-create-new-entry-with-existing-foreign-key) So it seems like there is no other way of doing that other than manually finding id and then attaching it directly to the new record. However I made a shortcut in order to handle such queries more easily. So I created new class, which extended from the sequelize model class and added new static function which handles fetching of id by itself:

```
export class CustomModel extends Model {
    static async getId<M extends Model>(attributes: M['_creationAttributes']) {
        const res = await this.findOne({where: attributes});
        if(!res) {
            throw new Error(`Can not find id of the record in the table ${this.tableName}`);
        }
        return res.get("id")
    }
}
```

And my models now extend from this class:

```
export class Sports extends CustomModel{
    static Leagues: HasMany<Sports, Leagues>;
}

Sports.init({
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {sequelize, tableName: 'sports'});
```

So now it is possible to add new records with already existing key with less code:

```
 await Leagues.create({name: "u", sports_id: await Sports.getId({name: "Basketball"})});
```